# Why am I getting segmentation Fault on fscanf() function?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I don't understand why I'm getting a segmentation fault when I call fscanf() function. I know I'm getting the file correctly opened using fopen().

```
ST_CHAR* GetLeafFromBitmap(const ST_CHAR* filename, ST_UINT8 u8dido, ST_UINT16 u16idx)
{
    FILE* fp;
    ST_CHAR* ps8buff;
    ST_CHAR ps8numstring[20];
    ST_CHAR* ps8curleaf;
    ST_CHAR  ps8didostr[10];
    ST_CHAR  ps8idxstr[10];

    sprintf(ps8idxstr, "%d", u16idx);   
    sprintf(ps8didostr, "%d", u8dido);
    strcpy(ps8numstring, ",");
    strcat(ps8numstring,ps8idxstr);
    strcat(ps8didostr, ps8numstring);
    printf("didostr : %s\n", ps8didostr);
    if((fp = fopen(filename, "r")) == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "\nError %d: Loading from \"%s\" file failed: %s\n", errno, filename, strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }       
    while(fscanf(fp, "%s", ps8buff) != EOF)
    {
        if(strstr(ps8buff, ps8didostr) != NULL)
        {
            ps8curleaf = GetLeaf(ps8buff);
            return ps8curleaf;
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

I'd really appreciate if any code guru can point out what I'm possibly doing wrong to get the error.

Comment: `ps8buff` is a pointer, but *where does it point?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ST_CHAR* ps8buff;
...
while(fscanf(fp, "%s", ps8buff) != EOF)
```

Two things:

1) You are writting to an uninitialized pointer, you need to reserve space for it (via `malloc`) or use an array like `ST_CHAR ps8buff[some_size];`

2) You don't have to check for `EOF` in `fscanf`, on success it returns the number of input items successfully matched and assigned, instead:

```
while(fscanf(fp, "%s", ps8buff) == 1)
```